# How to add Chromecast Support to a Javascript based video player

Tags: javascript, chromecast, google-cast

As I said in my title, I was wondering how I could add a cast button (For chromecast.) to a javascript based video player. Note, this player is a web player and integrated on this site: [twist.moe](http://twist.moe)
You can find the code for the player here, https://twist.moe/public/js/video.js But more over, I'm just wondering if its even possible to integrate the cast button into a javascript based player.

Comment: May sound weird, but by "*add a cast button (For chromecast.) to a javascript based video player*", do you mean that the video player will have the cast button and serve as the `sender`?

Comment: Yes actually! I want it to be able to stream video from the site, to the chromecast. But I have no idea of the possibility to do it with a javascript based player.

Comment: Did you find an answer? Because I am struggling to be able to discover devices on my network without creating a requestSession?